# Install automatically Java 8 on Windows Server AMI

Tags: java, windows, amazon-web-services

I am starting a Windows Server AMI and would need to have java 8 installed after boot. I already have an instance-setup.txt script to install the codedeploy-agent automatically (from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-set-up-new-instance.html), but would need to install Java 8 at the same time. I have no idea how to automatize this though, did anyone manage to do it successfully by any chance ?

Thanks !
Emmanuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java installers for Windows provide the ability to run an installation in silent mode via the command line or a script. If you package a Java installation executable with your deployment you can run a silent install like this:

```
jre-8-windows-i586.exe /s
```

Check out the documentation on Windows Installer Options for Java for more information and other available options: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html

Comment: It does not seem there is a way to configure the install to automatically set the PATH environment variable, but I can use a workaround.